# How to loop over map and generate JSX in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-map

This is my map:

```js
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set(0, 'foo');
map1.set(1, 'bar');
```

I want to generate a UI as

0: foo
1: bar
How can I generate this UI?

Thanks for the response.

But basically i have structure

```js
const data = {
  title: "hello lorem ipsum",
  replies: [
    {
      id: "1",
      parentId: null,
      body: "hello here i am",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      parentId: "1",
      body: "test it out",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      parentId: "2",
      body: "hello there!",
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      parentId: "3",
      body: "i dont continue testing",
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      parentId: "4",
      body: "this cannot be tested",
    },
    {
      id: "6",
      parentId: "4",
      body: "this is ridiculous",
    },
  ],
};
```

using this structure
i am trying to generate a tree kind of ui
which displays as this
hello here i am
test it out
hello there!
"i dont continue testing"
this cannot be tested. this is ridiculous"

as parent child relationship

i tried to make a datastructure using hashmap as

```js
function buildTreeMap() {
  const treeMap = new Map();
  for (const reply of data.replies) {
    const { id, parentId } = reply;
    let children = [];
    if (!parentId) {
      treeMap.set(id, []);
    } else {
      if (!treeMap.has(parentId)) {
        treeMap.set(parentId, [reply]);
      } else {
        children = treeMap.get(parentId);
        children.push(reply);
        treeMap.set(parentId, children);
      }
    }
  }
  return treeMap;
}
```

and my intention is to loop through this and generate the ui as mentioned above
I know this is similar to preorder

Comment: "_0->foo,1=> bar_" Is simply a line of text. By "UI", do you mean that line of text? If so, it's unclear what rules you intend to use to transform — also, why is the first arrow thin (`->`) while the second is wide (`=>`)? Why is there a space after the second, but not the first? etc... Please update the question to make it more clear. See [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.from` to convert the `Map` into an array
and then `map` over it:

```
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set(0, "foo");
map1.set(1, "bar");

function App() {
  return (
    <section>
      {Array.from(map1).map(([key, value]) => {
        return `${key}:${value}`;
      })}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Or, if you want each entry in a new line, replace the return statement like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <section>
      {Array.from(map1).map(([key, value]) => {
         return <p>{key}:{value}</p>;
      })}
    </section>
  );
}
```